# Qualtrics 2014 3D theme: Remove button gradient and change color

Tags: css, qualtrics

Folks,

Using CSS code snippets posted here, I have managed to change the styling of the next/previous buttons in most survey themes. However, the newest themes ("Qualtrics 3D - Gold" & "Qualtrics 3D - 2014") don't allow me to change the styling of the buttons. Basically, I haven't identified the elements on the page correctly (or am too unfamiliar with CSS). Has anyone managed to change the buttons for those themes (including hover-over style?).

Thanks!
Gowanus

Comment: Consider posting an example of the CSS, and a demo page to the survey.

Comment: what is it you were hoping to get out of this question?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help - here are two examples - the first one does what it is supposed to do - but when I switch survey themes, the custom CSS does not change the button color. I am looking for the CSS to achive the custom button color in the second example, with the 3D Theme: 1) https://baruch.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_cNlnhf8rSIdd4jj 2) https://baruch.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_5vTXBgFy0ao6w8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS code:

```
.Skin #Buttons #NextButton, .Skin #Buttons #PreviousButton {
    border: 1px solid #283b9a;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#3876d3 0,#27a3b1 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#3876d3 0,#27a3b1 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#3876d3 0,#27a3b1 100%);
}
```

This should help you change the color from red to blue for this [survey](https://baruch.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_5vTXBgFy0ao6w8B)

- To change border color, replace this color: `#283b9a`
- To change background, replace these two colors: `#3876d3` and `#27a3b1`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for - would not have figured that out without help - thanks!!